# Python Requests Data Not in Source Page (requests.get)

Tags: python

From the following link I cannot **scrape** data because requests work on source page but this site don't have required data in the python generated source page.
I am using requests.get method.
https://www.rcsb.org/search?request=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22parameters%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22hbb%22%7D%2C%22type%22%3A%22terminal%22%2C%22service%22%3A%22text%22%2C%22node_id%22%3A0%7D%2C%22return_type%22%3A%22entry%22%2C%22request_options%22%3A%7B%22pager%22%3A%7B%22start%22%3A0%2C%22rows%22%3A25%7D%2C%22scoring_strategy%22%3A%22combined%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%5B%7B%22sort_by%22%3A%22score%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22desc%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%22request_info%22%3A%7B%22src%22%3A%22ui%22%2C%22query_id%22%3A%229185f4458c49741d6003f0a9aa8935c2%22%7D%7D
Can any one help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That site is built dynamically using Javascript.  You will have to use something like Selenium, which uses a Chrome browser in the background to run the Javascript.  The `requests-HTML` module does the same thing in a way familiar to `requests` users.